# Subversion not updating original project?

Tags: svn, rapidsvn

I am new to subversion, I have imported an web project that we have been working on.
We are able to access everything via the repository. We can checkout files, update them, commit them, and all of the changes can be seen by other users.

My question is, shouldn't it write back to the original project folder I imported? I can not see the changes made there, only in the repository?

Comment: No, the original project folder is not a working copy.

Comment: When you imported the file, the original folder is just a source not a working copy. To make the folder an working copy, checkout on to the same folder from repo. I know there should have been a shortcut to do this. But the idea is similiar to almost all version control system.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Import** code into SVN repository
2. **Checkout** code to any location (create a working copy)
3. Make your changes
4. **Commit** the changes to SVN repository
5. Other users can receive the changes by running SVN **Update** command against their working copies

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you will get your sources from **import_repo** and work/commit changes with **work_repo**.

- `Import` from your **import_repo**, or ignore this step if **import_repo** is **work_repo**. You are getting the files contained in the repo
- `Checkout` with **work_repo**. You are creating a link between your local folder and the repo
- `Update` your working copy (your folder on your hard drive), it is a synchronization
  from the repo to your local sources
- Make your modifications
- `Add` the files you newly created or `delete` the ones you want to get rid of. It won't add or delete right now, but they will be tagged for the next commit
- `Commit`, it is the synchronization from your local sources to your repo

Check the presence of `.svn` files. They are your "synchronization" with the repo's sources.

If you imported your project, you have broken the link with the repository (like a simple copy/paste of the sources).

If you want to keep the synchronization, try to `checkout` instead.

Comment: I just want to clarify since I am a new to subversion.  I just installed subversion, I used the subversion import command to copy a project we have been working before subversion was installed. 
What was the workflow I should have done?